# Webrick Rails Server doesn't run correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webrick, mysql2

I have spent the last 6 hours fixing issues like modifying the $PATH, installing Gems to finally get everything as it should be.
but after I create the project folder with it's components and trying to run the server, I got this message :-

```
\KAMAL$ ls
Gemfile     README.rdoc app     config.ru   doc     log     script      tmp
Gemfile.lock    Rakefile    config      db      lib     public      test        vendor
\KAMAL$ rails server
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.13 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/client.rb:44:in `connect': Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) (Mysql2::Error)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/client.rb:44:in `initialize'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:16:in `new'
```

### "and many many lines as the same above"

the gem list
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

```
actionmailer (3.2.13)
actionpack (3.2.13)
activemodel (3.2.13)
activerecord (3.2.13)
activeresource (3.2.13)
activesupport (3.2.13)
arel (3.0.2)
builder (3.0.4)
bundler (1.3.5)
coffee-rails (3.2.2)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.6.2)
erubis (2.7.0)
execjs (1.4.0)
hike (1.2.2)
i18n (0.6.1)
journey (1.0.4)
jquery-rails (2.2.1)
json (1.7.7)
mail (2.5.3)
mime-types (1.22)
multi_json (1.7.2)
mysql2 (0.3.11)
polyglot (0.3.3)
rack (1.4.5)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-ssl (1.3.3)
rack-test (0.6.2)
rails (3.2.13)
railties (3.2.13)
rake (10.0.4)
rdoc (3.12.2)
rubygems-update (2.0.3)
sass (3.2.7)
sass-rails (3.2.6)
sprockets (2.2.2)
thor (0.18.1)
tilt (1.3.7)
treetop (1.4.12)
tzinfo (0.3.37)
uglifier (2.0.1)
webrick (1.3.1)
```

---

please help

Comment: What does your `config/database.yml` look like?  Under `development` it seems you've specified `mysql` as the adapter, and `root` as the user.  Look at the `database` name in that configuration, and verify with your MySQL client whether or not the root user can connect to that database.  Also, why do you think this is WEBrick's fault?

Answer (score 2):

This log entry

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) (Mysql2::Error)
```

Shows that you are using the user root at localhost without password as database. MySQL don't find this as a valid user. the following line should issue the same error message:

```
mysql -u root -h localhost
```

So check your database user/password in your `db/database.yml` file

Comment: I have a password for mysql I connect to mysql via the terminal with the password and I did show the databases without a problem

Comment: whe do I find the db/database.yml file

Comment: @Ahmedelhamahmy the file is in `path/to/your/application/db/database.yml`. I strongly recommend you to follow the [ruby guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/) to understand better what you are doing.

Comment: Why The Server starts and Ends directly and I canot access it on browser under localhost:3000

Comment: @Ahmedelhamahmy because it can't access the database and you have models that extendes ActiveRecord::Base, so it is a pre-requisite to run. Sorry, I'll not answer your questions any longer, I stronlgy recommend you to take a Rails curse or something.